# Алатырь-камень

Tags: этимология

Алатырь-камень - священный камень и символ у древних славян, центр мира. А что означает слово "алатырь"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этимология слова затемнена. Прошлась по этимологическим словарям, кое-что нашла только у Фасмера. Привожу статью почти полностью.

Ал**а**тырь. 
Ближайшая этимология: "всем камням камень", близ которого упала Голубиная книга; также л**а**тырь. Согласно Веселовскому, Акад. Слов., Мочульскому и Ягичу, это чудесный камень, который был положен спасителем в основание Сионского храма. Он был принесен с Синая и поставлен там как алтарь. Несмотря на остроумную аргументацию, производить от лат. altare, др.-исл. altaristeinn затруднительно в фонетическом отношении. Попытка объяснить форму влиянием местн. н. Алатырь (Цишевский, AfslPh 16, 603 и сл.) не устраняет трудностей, так как этот город расположен не на старой русской территории и в стороне от главных районов распространения устного народного творчества. Неубедительно также предположение Соболевского -- из прилаг. *латыгорь от* латыгоръ "латыш" со ссылкой на мест. н. Латырево (владимирск.) наряду с Латыгорево (тверск.). Неудовлетворительно также объяснение из греч. Elektron, как и из др.-исл. leiðarsteinn "магнит" у Бодуэна де Куртенэ. По Далю (1, 24), камень называется также Ал**а**бор, Ал**а**б**ы**рь.

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю.

*Согласно точке зрения В. В. Мартынова, алатырь происходит от иран.* al-atar, букв. «бел-горюч», то есть эпитет камня является таким образом прямой славянской калькой его названия.*
(Вики)

Мне почему-то эта версия более всего нравится. Может потому, что не плодит сущностей. Принцип "бритвы Оккама" иногда оказывается очень кстати.

Answer (score 0):

Этимологический словарь русского языка Макса Фасмера 
(онлайн версия).

Этимологический словарь русского языка Макса Фасмера принадлежит к числу самых авторитетных этимологических словарей нашего времени. Он содержит 18 тысяч словарных статей. Автор словаря - крупнейший этимолог-славист - дает сводку этимологических исследований.

Алатырь
(Ала́тырь):

город в Чувашской АССР. Из тюрк., тур. и т. д. ala "пестрый, пятнистый" и алт., тел., леб., шор., койб. tura 1) "дом", "строение, жилище", 2) "город", о которых см. Радлов 1, 351 и сл. и 3, 1446. Ср. Ala Šähär (местн. н.), Ala Daɣ (название гор)."
Учитывая колоссальное влияние на язык, мифологию, космогонию славян соседей тюрков (но никак не иранцев), слово "алатырь" может быть переведено на русский язык как "пестрый камень". Такие камни использовавались при строительстве зданий, в том числе храмов. Тем более, что это слово сохранилось в неизменном виде как топоним у тюрков.